# Run XSL transformation if match in array, how to discard if not?

Tags: xml, bash, xslt

I want to import certain articles into a database, based on their articlenumber. The article numbers that are allowed are in the "allowedArticles" variable. If the article is allowed to be imported, everything from that article should be imported. (The list of articles will be larger, the example below is just that, an example.)

The articles that do NOT match one of the articles in my list, should be discarded in some kind of way.

This XSLT will be run on multiple files, because the export have been made with one item in each file, though this could be all items in one big file. Would it be easier to do what I want with one big file?

Is this possible with XSLT, if so, what's the best solution? Should I rather go about writing a bash-script that can support this operation?

Do you need any more information?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.escenic.com/2009/import">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- Array of articles to include in the import, optimize by loading from external file -->
  <xsl:variable name="allowedArticles" as="element()*">
    <Item>86369</Item><Item>81563</Item><Item>68333</Item><Item>67772</Item>
  </xsl:variable>


  <!-- If the article ID is NOT in allowedArticles do nothing with them -->
  <xsl:template match="/escenic/content">
    <xsl:variable name="exportedDbId" select="@exported-dbid" />
    <xsl:for-each select="$allowedArticles">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$exportedDbId=.">
          <!-- Identity template : copy all text nodes, elements and attributes -->
          <!-- It does not work to copy all nodes from here, as it's the wrong context or something like that. -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise />
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The articles that do NOT match one of the articles in my list, should be discarded in some kind of way.*

So if I undertand correct, and all you want to do is remove the elements that are "not allowed" you can simply do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://xmlns.escenic.com/2009/import">

<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:variable name="allowedArticles" as="element()*">
    <Item>86369</Item><Item>81563</Item><Item>68333</Item><Item>67772</Item>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- empty template to discard content elements that are not in allowedArticles -->
<xsl:template match="content[not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles/Item)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The identity template will copy everything, the empty template will match on your not allowed articles and discard them.

**Edit:**

As @tomalak suggested a sequence would be a more elegant way to handle your Allowed Id's:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedItems" select="(86369, 81563, 68333, 67772)"/>
```

To answer the questions from the comments, this is equal to:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedItems">
    <xsl:sequence select="(86369, 81563, 68333, 67772)"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

If you want to reference the AllowedItems from an external file, let's say you have a file called AllowedItems.xml that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AllowedItems>
    <Item>86369</Item>
    <Item>81563</Item>
    <Item>68333</Item>
    <Item>67772</Item>
</AllowedItems>
```

You'd then define your variable like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="AllowedItems"
     select="document('AllowedItems.xml')/AllowedItems/Item"/>
```

The `document()` function here expects the AllowedItems.xml to be in the same directory as your xslt, you can also use a relative path or a full Uri here, you can read up on document [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-document).

---

*This XSLT will be run on multiple files, because the export have been made with one item in each file, though this could be all items in one big file. Would it be easier to do what I want with one big file?*

I think this is a matter of preference and/or performance and depends on your input file(s) and your specific scenario. I'd generally prefer one transformation over a lot of smaller ones however the bigger the file gets you might be better of with multiple transformations.

Comment: FYI: `content[not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles/Item)]` matches elements that do not even have an `@exported-dbid` attribute. This might or might not be desired. Also, you can work with `<xsl:sequence select="(86369, 81563, 68333, 67772)" />`, that's easier to manage.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that, however whenever you use an inclusive selection like here I'd figure anything that does not have an Id that is in my list should be discarded. Your right about the sequence though, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: It was more of an FYI for the OP anyway. :)

Comment: Thank you both. @TobiasKlevenz you wrote xsl:variable instead of xsl:sequence in your edit. Are they equal? I will test your suggestion as soon as I have time, and then probably accept your answer.

Comment: And could the allowed articles also be fetched from a file, with say, each article number on one line?

Comment: I have tested your solution, and it works if I use this line <xsl:template match="escenic/content[not(@exported-dbid=$allowedArticles)]" /> i.e. remove /Item in the end. What I can not get to work, is fetching from the external file. I get nothing when using <xsl:variable name="AllowedItems"
     select="document('AllowedItems.xml')/AllowedItems/Item"/>, but if I remove /AllowedItems/Item I get the root element with the content, but then the matching does not work anymore. Do any of you have any suggestions on what this might be? @Tomalak

Comment: It's probably a namespace issue, either add your own or the namespace of your source xml to the AllowedItems.xml

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I removed the default xpath namespace and used the namespace on each of the elements instead, then I did not have to declare a namespace on the external file at all. Thanks for your help, I have accepted and upvoted your answer.